# Make UIScrollView give up UITouch

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uitouch, touch-event

I have a drawing app with a canvas larger than the size of the phone screen. I want to implement scrolling with two fingers and drawing with one finger. So far I can make the scrolling work just fine but when it comes to drawing, the line begins and then the view where the drawing is loses control of the touch such that only the first part of the line is drawn. I think the scrollview takes control back. Dots can be draw just fine.

This is my subclassed UIScrollView

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touches = event?.touches(for: self) else { return }
    if touches.count < 2 {
        self.next?.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    } else {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touches = event?.touches(for: self) else { return }
    if touches.count < 2 {
        self.next?.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    } else {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touches = event?.touches(for: self) else { return }
    if touches.count < 2 {
        self.next?.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    } else {
        super.touchesMoved(touches, with: event)
    }
}

override func touchesCancelled(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touches = event?.touches(for: self) else { return }
    if touches.count < 2 {
        self.next?.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    } else {
        super.touchesCancelled(touches, with: event)
    }
}

override func touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView) -> Bool {
    if (type(of: view)) == UIScrollView.self {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Long Press Gesture Recognizer connected to your ScrollerView, set with **Min Duration 0 seconds**, also to recognize **only 1 Touch** and **Cancel touches in view** option active.

You can find all these options under the Attributes Inspector on Interface Builder.

Please play a little with the Tolerance settings to fine tune the results.

Comment: I do have the **cancel touches in view option active** but sorry what do you mean by recognize only 1 touch? I still want the the scroll view to recognize 2 touches AS WELL AS pass the 1 touch through to the next responder, which would be my canvas. I'll try the Long Press Gesture Recognizer but I need to update the canvas very often to simulate drawing and I was hoping to use the touchesmoved method because I'm not sure how I'd accomplish that in the recognizer's selector, thank you for the answer btw will try!

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I was not clear. 

You should rely on the GestureRecognizer to capture the touches and act accordingly, effectively cancelling the touch for the underlying views.

I used this setup successfully to capture drawing and gestures before.

From what I understand UIScrollView can't manage effectively the pan/drag gestures to pass them to the views it contains.

Comment: Yeah I was! I actually used a different solution which was to subclass UIScrollView and add the views I wanted to have the touch as subviews to the subclass instead of subviews of the common parent viewcontroller. Then the UIScrollView never asked for the touch back because it was already response for the action. It's working perfectly now but thanks I appreciate your answer!